# Thunderbolt - Displayport Monitors not detected on reboot. XPS 13 Arch Linux (endeavourOS)

Tags: multi-monitor, displayport, endeavouros

I am running EndeavourOS (Arch) on a 2017 Dell XPS 13. Kernel 5.7.2-arch1-1
[Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 13 9360/02PG84, BIOS 2.13.0 11/14/2019]

I have a multi-monitor setup at my desk, that, when working has the following config:

### xrandr:

```
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 290mm x 170mm
   1920x1080     59.93*+  59.93  

DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1-1 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     60.00 +  30.00    25.00    24.00*   29.97    23.98    29.98  

DP1-2 connected 1440x2560+5760+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 520mm x 300mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
```

I have deleted the inactive rows to keep this short(er).

DP1-1 and DP 1-2 are connected over a passive thunderbolt to dual display port adapter.

On restart (not on short reboot) the monitors are not detected and the only way I have found to have the OS detect them is to unplug both of them either at the monitor or the display port sockets on the adapter, then plug them back in one by one.  Unplugging the adapter at the thunderbolt/usbc port does not result in the monitors working or even showing up in the xrandr output (journal output below after unplugging and re-adding the adapter at the thunderbolt port.

Is there a way to have these monitors consistently detected on reboot, or failing that - a way to 'jolt' the os into detecting them?

Below is the output from `lspic` and `journalctl` just after plugging each monitor back in.

I have inspected the journal from boot and am not finding anything that looks (to me) like the system failing when trying to detect the monitors.

Any help appreciated.

### lspci

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)

01:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
02:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
02:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
39:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation DSL6340 USB 3.1 Controller [Alpine Ridge]
```

### Here is the output from the journal after plugging monitors back in:

Monitor 1

```
Jun 22 09:53:32 lvtu autorandr[7579]: Failed to load profile 'default': Profile not found (line 1413)
Jun 22 09:53:32 lvtu autorandr[7579]: autorandr running as user richardp (started from batch instance)
Jun 22 09:53:32 lvtu autorandr[7579]: home
Jun 22 09:53:32 lvtu autorandr[7573]: Running autorandr as richardp for display :0
Jun 22 09:53:32 lvtu systemd[1]: autorandr.service: Succeeded.
Jun 22 09:53:32 lvtu systemd[1]: Finished autorandr execution hook.
Jun 22 09:53:32 lvtu audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=autorandr comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jun 22 09:53:32 lvtu audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=autorandr comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jun 22 09:53:32 lvtu kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1592790812.037:119): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=autorandr comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? 
res=success'
Jun 22 09:53:32 lvtu kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1592790812.037:120): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=autorandr comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? 
res=success'
Jun 22 09:53:32 lvtu kernel: [drm:drm_dp_mst_dpcd_read [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* mstb 00000000c66618ae port 1: DPCD read on addr 0x4b0 for 1 bytes NAKed
Jun 22 09:53:33 lvtu systemd[1]: Starting autorandr execution hook...
Jun 22 09:53:33 lvtu /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1857]: (II) intel(0): Output DP1-2 has no monitor section
Jun 22 09:53:33 lvtu /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1857]: (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP1-2
Jun 22 09:53:33 lvtu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in First Boot Wizard being skipped.
Jun 22 09:53:33 lvtu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
Jun 22 09:53:33 lvtu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Dynamic Linker Cache being skipped.
Jun 22 09:53:33 lvtu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Store a System Token in an EFI Variable being skipped.
Jun 22 09:53:33 lvtu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
Jun 22 09:53:33 lvtu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Journal Catalog being skipped.
Jun 22 09:53:33 lvtu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Commit a transient machine-id on disk being skipped.
Jun 22 09:53:33 lvtu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Create System Users being skipped.
Jun 22 09:53:33 lvtu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Update is Completed being skipped.
Jun 22 09:53:33 lvtu /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1857]: (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 3360x2560
Jun 22 09:53:33 lvtu /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1857]: (II) intel(0): switch to mode 2560x1440@60.0 on DP1-2 using pipe 1, position (1920, 0), rotation left, reflection none
Jun 22 09:53:34 lvtu autorandr[7597]: Failed to load profile 'default': Profile not found (line 1413)
Jun 22 09:53:34 lvtu autorandr[7597]: autorandr running as user richardp (started from batch instance)
Jun 22 09:53:34 lvtu autorandr[7597]: home
Jun 22 09:53:34 lvtu autorandr[7588]: Running autorandr as richardp for display :0
Jun 22 09:53:34 lvtu systemd[1]: autorandr.service: Succeeded.
Jun 22 09:53:34 lvtu systemd[1]: Finished autorandr execution hook.
Jun 22 09:53:34 lvtu audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=autorandr comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jun 22 09:53:34 lvtu audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=autorandr comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jun 22 09:53:34 lvtu kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1592790814.441:121): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=autorandr comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? 
res=success'
Jun 22 09:53:34 lvtu kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1592790814.441:122): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=autorandr comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? 
res=success'
Jun 22 09:53:39 lvtu kernel: [drm:drm_dp_mst_dpcd_read [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* mstb 00000000c66618ae port 1: DPCD read on addr 0x4b0 for 1 bytes NAKed
```

Monitor 2:

```
Jun 22 09:55:18 lvtu autorandr[7949]: Failed to load profile 'default': Profile not found (line 1413)
Jun 22 09:55:18 lvtu autorandr[7949]: autorandr running as user richardp (started from batch instance)
Jun 22 09:55:18 lvtu autorandr[7949]: home
Jun 22 09:55:18 lvtu autorandr[7943]: Running autorandr as richardp for display :0
Jun 22 09:55:18 lvtu systemd[1]: autorandr.service: Succeeded.
Jun 22 09:55:18 lvtu systemd[1]: Finished autorandr execution hook.
Jun 22 09:55:18 lvtu audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=autorandr comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jun 22 09:55:18 lvtu audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=autorandr comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jun 22 09:55:18 lvtu kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1592790918.282:123): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=autorandr comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? 
res=success'
Jun 22 09:55:18 lvtu kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1592790918.282:124): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=autorandr comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? 
res=success'
Jun 22 09:55:18 lvtu /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1857]: (--) intel(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 600000KHz
Jun 22 09:55:35 lvtu fcitx.desktop[2664]: (WARN-2664 x11selection.c:309) Selection is too long.
```

### journal output after plugging in adapter at the thunderbolt port:

```
richardp@lvtu: journalctl --follow
Jun 23 10:34:34 lvtu /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1695]: (--) intel(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 600000KHz
Jun 23 10:43:31 lvtu kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
Jun 23 10:43:31 lvtu kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
Jun 23 10:43:31 lvtu kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: EDR: ACPI event 0x0 received
Jun 23 10:43:31 lvtu kernel: hub 3-0:1.0: activate --> -19
Jun 23 10:43:31 lvtu kernel: usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
Jun 23 10:43:31 lvtu kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: remove, state 4
Jun 23 10:43:31 lvtu kernel: usb usb4: USB disconnect, device number 1
Jun 23 10:43:31 lvtu kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: USB bus 4 deregistered
Jun 23 10:43:31 lvtu kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: remove, state 1
Jun 23 10:43:31 lvtu kernel: usb usb3: USB disconnect, device number 1
Jun 23 10:43:31 lvtu kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: Host halt failed, -19
Jun 23 10:43:31 lvtu kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: Host not accessible, reset failed.
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: USB bus 3 deregistered
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: pci_bus 0000:02: Allocating resources
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: pcieport 0000:02:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 39] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: pcieport 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: pcieport 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: pcieport 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: pcieport 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: sysfs group 'power' not found for kobject 'i2c-10'
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 5822 at fs/sysfs/group.c:279 sysfs_remove_group+0x6f/0x80
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: Modules linked in: uinput xt_connmark nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c xt_mark iptable_mangle xt_comment xt_addrtype iptable_raw wireguard curve25519_x86_64 libchacha20poly1305 chacha_x86_64 poly1305_x86_64 libblake2s blake2s_x86_64 ip6_udp_tunnel udp_tunnel libcurve25519_generic libchacha libblake2s_generic tun thunderbolt fuse rfcomm uas hid_logitech_hidpp usb_storage hid_logitech_dj usbhid smsc75xx usbnet mii udl cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep typec_displayport uvcvideo btusb videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops btbcm videobuf2_v4l2 btintel videobuf2_common bluetooth videodev mc ecdh_generic ecc snd_hda_codec_hdmi hid_multitouch hid_generic snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic joydev mousedev iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support snd_soc_skl snd_soc_sst_ipc x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_hda_ext_core coretemp snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi kvm_intel snd_soc_core snd_compress kvm ac97_bus irqbypass i915
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel:  mei_hdcp snd_pcm_dmaengine mei_wdt intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_intel crct10dif_pclmul wmi_bmof snd_intel_dspcfg dell_wmi ath10k_pci intel_wmi_thunderbolt crc32_pclmul dell_laptop ghash_clmulni_intel ath10k_core mmc_block snd_hda_codec ledtrig_audio dell_smbios snd_hda_core nls_iso8859_1 dell_wmi_descriptor ath snd_hwdep nls_cp437 dcdbas aesni_intel i2c_algo_bit crypto_simd vfat squashfs cryptd glue_helper mac80211 fat drm_kms_helper snd_pcm intel_cstate cec snd_timer rc_core intel_uncore snd cfg80211 intel_rapl_perf intel_gtt psmouse pcspkr input_leds syscopyarea soundcore i2c_i801 intel_lpss_pci mei_me ucsi_acpi rfkill processor_thermal_device intel_xhci_usb_role_switch i2c_hid typec_ucsi intel_lpss intel_rapl_common libarc4 sysfillrect mei roles idma64 intel_soc_dts_iosf intel_pch_thermal typec hid sysimgblt fb_sys_fops wmi battery soc_button_array intel_vbtn evdev intel_hid int3403_thermal int3400_thermal int340x_thermal_zone sparse_keymap acpi_thermal_rel mac_hid ac drm loop sg
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel:  crypto_user agpgart ip_tables x_tables ext4 crc32c_generic crc16 mbcache jbd2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc serio_raw mmc_core atkbd libps2 crc32c_intel xhci_pci rtsx_pci xhci_hcd i8042 serio
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 5822 Comm: kworker/1:2 Tainted: G     U            5.7.2-arch1-1 #1
[Duplicated output]
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 13 9360/02PG84, BIOS 2.13.0 11/14/2019
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: Workqueue: events drm_dp_delayed_destroy_work [drm_kms_helper]
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: RIP: 0010:sysfs_remove_group+0x6f/0x80
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: Code: ff 5b 48 89 ef 5d 41 5c e9 ae c1 ff ff 48 89 ef e8 96 ba ff ff eb d1 49 8b 14 24 48 8b 33 48 c7 c7 b8 be 77 97 e8 48 5c d0 ff <0f> 0b 5b 5d 41 5c c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb25fc2f2bd38 EFLAGS: 00010282
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffffff974ea4a0 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000000086 RDI: 00000000ffffffff
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 0000000000000512 R09: 0000000000000001
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff9b04133e08a8
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: R13: ffff9b04133e0928 R14: dead000000000100 R15: ffff9b04133e0900
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9b05ae440000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: CR2: 000055e38ec6d800 CR3: 000000014640a004 CR4: 00000000003606e0
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: Call Trace:
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel:  device_del+0x97/0x3f0
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel:  device_unregister+0x16/0x60
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel:  i2c_del_adapter+0x23d/0x300
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel:  drm_dp_port_set_pdt+0x98/0x2c0 [drm_kms_helper]
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel:  drm_dp_delayed_destroy_work+0x235/0x320 [drm_kms_helper]
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel:  process_one_work+0x1da/0x3d0
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel:  worker_thread+0x4d/0x3e0
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel:  ? rescuer_thread+0x3f0/0x3f0
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel:  kthread+0x13e/0x160
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel:  ? __kthread_bind_mask+0x60/0x60
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu kernel: ---[ end trace 6d0f32557a6e8871 ]---
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in First Boot Wizard being skipped.
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Dynamic Linker Cache being skipped.
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Store a System Token in an EFI Variable being skipped.
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Journal Catalog being skipped.
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Commit a transient machine-id on disk being skipped.
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Create System Users being skipped.
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Update is Completed being skipped.
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu systemd[1]: Starting autorandr execution hook...
Jun 23 10:43:32 lvtu /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1695]: (II) intel(0): Disabled output DP1-2
Jun 23 10:43:33 lvtu /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1695]: (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 1920x1080
Jun 23 10:43:33 lvtu autorandr[14219]: Failed to load profile 'default': Profile not found (line 1413)
Jun 23 10:43:33 lvtu autorandr[14219]: autorandr running as user richardp (started from batch instance)
Jun 23 10:43:33 lvtu autorandr[14219]: home
Jun 23 10:43:33 lvtu autorandr[14213]: Running autorandr as richardp for display :0
Jun 23 10:43:33 lvtu systemd[1]: autorandr.service: Succeeded.
Jun 23 10:43:33 lvtu systemd[1]: Finished autorandr execution hook.
Jun 23 10:43:33 lvtu audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=autorandr comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jun 23 10:43:33 lvtu audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=autorandr comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jun 23 10:43:33 lvtu kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1592880213.962:158): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=autorandr comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jun 23 10:43:33 lvtu kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1592880213.962:159): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=autorandr comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? 
res=success'
Jun 23 10:43:37 lvtu kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
Jun 23 10:43:37 lvtu kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jun 23 10:43:37 lvtu kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:   device [8086:9d10] error status/mask=00002001/00002000
Jun 23 10:43:37 lvtu kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jun 23 10:43:37 lvtu kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: EDR: ACPI event 0x0 received
Jun 23 10:43:37 lvtu kernel: pcieport 0000:02:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
Jun 23 10:43:37 lvtu kernel: pci_bus 0000:03: busn_res: [bus 03] is released
Jun 23 10:43:37 lvtu kernel: pci_bus 0000:04: busn_res: [bus 04-38] is released
Jun 23 10:43:37 lvtu kernel: pci_bus 0000:39: busn_res: [bus 39] is released
Jun 23 10:43:37 lvtu kernel: pci_bus 0000:02: busn_res: [bus 02-39] is released
Jun 23 10:43:37 lvtu boltd[2868]: probing: removing /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0 from roots
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: EDR: ACPI event 0x0 received
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0: [8086:1576] type 01 class 0x060400
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0: supports D1 D2
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0: 15.752 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 8.0 GT/s PCIe x2 link at 0000:00:1c.0 (capable of 31.504 Gb/s with 8.0 GT/s PCIe x4 link)
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: [8086:1576] type 01 class 0x060400
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: supports D1 D2
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:01.0: [8086:1576] type 01 class 0x060400
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:01.0: enabling Extended Tags
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:01.0: supports D1 D2
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:01.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0: [8086:1576] type 01 class 0x060400
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0: enabling Extended Tags
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0: supports D1 D2
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02-39]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xda0fffff]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xda000000-0xda0fffff]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04-38]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xd9efffff]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:39:00.0: [8086:15b5] type 00 class 0x0c0330
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:39:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xd9f00000-0xd9f0ffff]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:39:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:39:00.0: supports D1 D2
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:39:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:39:00.0: 8.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 2.5 GT/s PCIe x4 link at 0000:02:02.0 (capable of 31.504 Gb/s with 8.0 GT/s PCIe x4 link)
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 39]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd9f00000-0xd9ffffff]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci_bus 0000:02: Allocating resources
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:01.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 04-38] add_size 1000
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 39] add_size 1000
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 39] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 02-39] add_size 3000
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x2000-0x4fff]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:01.0: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x2000-0x2fff]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xda000000-0xda0fffff]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04-38]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [io  0x2000-0x2fff]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xd9efffff]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 39]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd9f00000-0xd9ffffff]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02-39]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [io  0x2000-0x4fff]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xda0fffff]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pcieport 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pcieport 0000:02:01.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: pcieport 0000:02:02.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x110 quirks 0x0000000200009810
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.07
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 5.7.2-arch1-1 xhci-hcd
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:39:00.0
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: Host supports USB 3.1 Enhanced SuperSpeed
Jun 23 10:43:42 lvtu kernel: usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.07
```

Comment: Update, turning the mains power to the monitors off and on causes them to be detected. This is a superior work  around to reaching behind the monitors and fumbling about with DP sockets...